# Using Tor to make HTTPS requests in Python

Tags: python, https, stem, url

I have the following code:

```
with Controller.from_port(port = 9151) as controller:

                    controller.authenticate()
                    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9150)
                    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
                    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)


                    url= "https://www.example.com"

                    browser = mechanize.Browser()

                    text = browser.open(url).read()
```

When I run it I get the following lengthy traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\HOJU\Desktop\edp\gog.py", line 168, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\HOJU\Desktop\edp\gog.py", line 101, in main
        text = browser.open(url).read()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 203, in      ope
    n
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 230, in _me
ch_open
    response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_opener.py", line 193, in open
    response = urlopen(self, req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 344, in
_open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 332, in
_call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 1170, in
 https_open
    return self.do_open(conn_factory, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 1115, in
 do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 946, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 987, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 940, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 803, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 755, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1152, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\HOJU\Desktop\edp\gog.py", line 32, in create_connection
    sock.connect(address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 392, in connect
    self.__negotiatesocks5(destpair[0],destpair[1])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 199, in __negotiatesocks5
    self.sendall("\x05\x01\x00")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 165, in sendall
    socket.socket.sendall(self, bytes)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 165, in sendall
    socket.socket.sendall(self, bytes)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 165, in sendall
    socket.socket.sendall(self, bytes)                     
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 165, in sendall
    socket.socket.sendall(self, bytes)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 165, in sendall
    socket.socket.sendall(self, bytes)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 165, in sendall
    socket.socket.sendall(self, bytes)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 163, in sendall
    if 'encode' in dir(bytes):
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you use the Stem library?

Comment: yes i do use the stem library. i was actually able to resolve the above issue . now the programs runs properly. However when it opens the url for the google page that i am trying to read i get a 503 error, do you know why this happens? @JensKubieziel

Comment: @JensKubieziel does google automatically block a request if it sees that it comes from a Tor network?

Comment: @abcla No it does not blocks a request from Tor on automatical basis

Comment: @abcla please answer your question and describe what you did to resolve your issue. This helps other people which might run into the same problem.

Comment: @abcla Google doesn't do it automatically, but sometimes they think an ip address does abuse and block this address.

Comment: the cause to the problem was that i was using the SocksiPy module downloaded from pip, the script that was obtained with pip is not proper. to solve the problem i went into C:\Python\Lib\site-packages and deleted the current socks PY file and downloaded the new one from the offical website: http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/ then placed the new file back in the site-packages folder to replace the new one

Answer (score 1):

Here are your [pyCURL](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html#setting-options) and a [howto](http://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2015/02/22/pycurl-through-tor-without-leaking-dns-lookups/)

UPDATE: Copy-pasting by request - copyright to code to sources mentioned upstrings:

```
amnesia@amnesia: ~$ cat checkTor.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pycurl

curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt( pycurl.URL, 'https://check.torproject.org/' )
curl.setopt( pycurl.PROXY, '127.0.0.1' )
curl.setopt( pycurl.PROXYPORT, 9050 )
curl.setopt( pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME )

curl.perform()
amnesia@amnesia: ~$ time ./checkTor.py
<!doctype html>
...
Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.
...
real 0m2.487s
user 0m0.060s
sys 0m0.000s
```

That is your HTTPS request via Tor, no DNS leaks. Your STEM request **must not use proxy** - Tor does not allow LAN IP's through SOCKS, and it's correct. You must not use any proxies *sending signal NEWNYM*. To capture HTML output use cURL options like RETURN_TRANSFER - see docs to fit your needs

Comment: Your answer is not really helpful as it stands. Please describe a specific solution to the question. Links to other sites might disappear.

Comment: @JensKubieziel would you please be so kind reading the links  provided **before** complaining about the answer? If the links to the cURL for Python official site will be dead - then pycurl itself will be dead and an answer will be useles even if there will be a full copy-paste. Or should I attach an official repository source code snapshot too? For a case, you know? This is really ridiculous complain, man! No offense - just check the links and smile =)